# Strip IFRAME from ASP String

Tags: html, string, iframe, asp-classic

**I'd like to specifically strip any `<iframe>` code from my ASP String.**

I'm currently using this:

```
Function stripTags(HTMLstring)
    Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
    With RegularExpressionObject
        .Pattern = "<[^>]+>"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    stripTags = RegularExpressionObject.Replace(HTMLstring, "")
    Set RegularExpressionObject = nothing
End Function
```

However, I realise this will remove ALL HTML, not just IFRAME code.

**Can someone help?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Function stripIframeTags(HTMLstring)
    Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
    With RegularExpressionObject
        .Pattern = "<iframe[^>]+>.*?</iframe>"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    stripIframeTags = RegularExpressionObject.Replace(HTMLstring, "")
    Set RegularExpressionObject = nothing
End Function
```

This assumes that there is always a closing tag to the iframe, but this could be marked optional in the regular expression.

Comment: Many thanks, gpinkas. I will try first thing tomorrow morning when I have server access. Will let you know :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here, is the thing.. i am not that good with regex, but i have a solution:

for open tag iframe
`<iframe src="">` the regex is

`<iframe[^>]+>`

---

for close tag `</iframe>` the regex is

`<[/iframe[^>]+>`

---

in the code:
.Pattern = "INSERT-IT-HERE"

Comment: I'll give this a whirl. Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: i have made some changes.. pls hav a look before trying

Comment: Can you explain (using my code) how I would implement this solution?